# Is the current Silverlight 4 beta supported on Visual Studio 2010 RC?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

As probably everyone knows, MS just released the RC for Visual Studio 2010 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd582936.aspx).  I'm about to download and install it, but I need to know if the current Silverlight 4 beta bits are supported.  Anyone happen to know, or know differently?  (If I don't get an answer, I'll post my results back here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot open a sl 4 beta app in vs2010 rc. Hopefully they will update the sl 4 beta soon

Answer (score 1):

ScottGu tweeted: "Support for Silverlight 4 with the VS 2010 RC will show up with next public SL4 drop (and so is not yet enabled with today's bits)".  Next question is when SL4 bits will be refreshed...

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to this now:

http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://sorokoletov.com/2010/02/hate-2-wait-silverlight-4-beta-2-vs-2010-rc/

For sure not everything will work, but it is beta and thats fine. I like many others don't have a second [fast] spare machine to run VS2010 Beta 2 on just to be able to continue using it.

I can confirm it will compile and run an app which is right now a lifesaver to me.

Issues I've found :

- Cannot seem to use `dynamic` keyword even in very simple cases.

  dynamic foo = 12;
   dynamic bar = 2;
   var total = foo + bar;

  *One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?* (yes I do have these DLLs and yes they are the silverlight 4 DLLS)

PLEASE ADD ADDITIONAL ISSUES TO THE COMMENTS